# Using Math.pow() function

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to make a program in Java to calculate the formula for the Ricker wavelet:

[image]

But the results are not matching to the real ones.

This is what I'm using:

```
private static double rickerWavelet(double t, double f){

   double p = (Math.pow(Math.PI, 2))*(Math.pow(f, 2))*(Math.pow(t, 2));

   double lnRicker = 1 - (2 * p) * Math.exp(-p);

   return lnRicker;
}
```

Am I using the Math functions wrongly?

Comment: You forgot brackets between your base and the exponent. `double lnRicker = (1 - (2 * p)) * Math.exp(-p);`

Comment: Aren't you missing braces here: double lnRicker = (1 - (2 * p)) * Math.exp(-p);

Comment: In what way don't match - by just a little? Consider using [`import static`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) to clean up your code. Also `PI*PI` etc is probably eaiser than `pow(PI, 2)`.

Comment: Some comments could be answers here..

Comment: Tell me about it, all that missed rep.

Comment: no need for brackets around `Math.pow()`

Comment: Math.pow is very expensive, you should perform `x * x` instead of `Math.pow(x, 2)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To match the formula,

```
double lnRicker = 1 - (2 * p) * Math.exp(-p);
```

needs to be

```
double lnRicker = (1 - (2 * p)) * Math.exp(-p);
```

Since `*` has higher operator precedence than `-`, in your expression the multiplication of `(2 * p)` with `Math.exp(-p)` will be done first, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just like to add that `Math.pow(x, 2)` can be written more simply (and possibly more accurately and more efficiently) as `x * x` ... for any variable or constant `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your executing equation if you know about BODMAS method:

You should  do:  `(1-(2*p))* Math.exp(-p);`

I just changed your equation by inserting round brackets around `1-2*p`..